# Implementing query "findByUsername" on Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

So, I´m currently on project where I have to create my own repositories without extending Jpa or CRUD repositories, i would like to know how I can implement the same method found in JpaRepository called "findByUsername" to work the same way. It receives a String and returns the whole Object in case it finds the username in the DB.

This is my UserDao

```
public interface UserDAO extends AbstractDAO<User, Long>{
User findByUsername (String username);
}
```

And this is my This is my UserDaoImplements there I need to implement the body of the method findByUsername:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl extends AbstractDAOImpl<User, Long> implements UserDAO {

@Override
public User findByUsername(String username) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have annotated your question with hibernate, I am suggesting to use EntityManager :

```
public class UserDAOImpl extends AbstractDAOImpl<User, Long> implements UserDAO {
@Autowired
EntityManager em;

@Override
public User findByUsername(String username) {
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from User where username = :username", User.class);
     q.setParameter("username", username);
     return (User)q.getSingleResult();
}
}
```

Comment: I assume you meant to use the username method parameter instead of "ABC"

Comment: @AlexandrTer  Yes that is correct.; edited my answer.

Comment: i tried this solution and found this error:

class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class rs.saga.obuka.sagashop.domain.User ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; rs.saga.obuka.sagashop.domain.User is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: @BelithoXavier , just updated my answer, you need to use overloaded method of `createNativeQuery(queryString, resultclass)`, please check & if it works let me know and accept answer. thanks

Comment: I´m so sorry, i didn't see that part of "User.class".
Answer accepted, worked perfectly

Comment: glad it worked for you :-) !